# How do I use environment variables (repl.it) to create an array?

Tags: php, replit, getenv

If you're not aware of this, environment variables are kind of like secret values in Repl.it as Repl.it makes your code publicly available for everybody.

I have a set of *keys* that I want to remain hidden on the website, and I want the website to randomize a key selection to distribute to the user on page load. Kind of a makeshift key system.

However, once I put the key values into the environment variable, and I try to load it into an array, this happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiSzm.png

This, in basis, is the code I'm using (I load the varaible $trollitem for display later on in the code, but that's just a bunch of HTML design)

```php
<?php
  $loadstring = getenv('cheatxkeys');
  $items = array($loadstring);
  $trollitem = $items[array_rand($items)];
?>
```

And finally, this is how my environment variable looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAqA6.png

For obvious reasons, these are not the actual key codes I'm using, but rather a randomly generated amount of key codes to show what I'm trying to do.

If my post is unclear, please just comment, I really want to get this to work properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your environment variable `$loadstring` is stored and retrieved as a string, and PHP `array()` takes as parameters all the elements of the array to be created. Therefore, `array($loadstring)` gives an array of length 1 with the full string stored in the environment variable as its only element.

It appears your string format is like a JSON array, but without the enclosing square brackets, so you can do this:

```php
$items = json_decode('[' . $loadstring . ']');
```

See also the [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) documentation.